Struggling with the LINQ method syntax to lookup a value
Getting this JSON from an API (GA4 metadata API)

{
  "dimensions": [
    {
      ....
    }
  ],
  "metrics": [
    ....
    {
      "apiName": "keyEvents",
      "uiName": "Key events",
      "description": "The count of key events. Marking an event as a key event affects reports from time of creation. It doesn't change historic data. You can mark any event as key in Google Analytics, and some events (such as `first_open` or `purchase`) are marked as key events by default.",
      "deprecatedApiNames": [
        "conversions"
      ],
      "type": "TYPE_FLOAT",
      "category": "Event"
    },
    {
      "apiName": "newUsers",
      "uiName": "New users",
      "description": "The number of users who interacted with your site or launched your app for the first time (event triggered: first_open or first_visit).",
      "type": "TYPE_INTEGER",
      "category": "User"
    },


I have a function to return the uiName from an apiName:
I want to return the uiName where either the apiName matches or where it's present in the deprecated list.
But my Linq skills with JSON aren't up to the task. I figured it would be something like this, but
JsonElement doesn't have a method ToList().
    // param "type" in ["dimensions","metrics"]
    private string MemberFriendlyName(JsonDocument metadata, string type, string apiName)
    {
        string uiName = metadata
            .RootElement
            .GetProperty(type)
            .EnumerateArray()
            .Where(me => (
                (me.TryGetProperty("apiName", out me) && me.GetString() == apiName)
                    ||
                (me.TryGetProperty("deprecatedApiNames", out me) && me.ToList().Contains(apiName))
            ))
            //.Where(me => me.GetPropertyNullable("apiName")?.GetString() == apiName)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .GetPropertyNullable("uiName")?.GetString();
        return uiName;
    }



I always prefer and recommend to use deserialization into a class or hierarchy of classes. There are tools online to generate such classes from JSON text, and Visual Studio also has a feature that does just that: (1) copy JSON text to clipboard, (2) "Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes". That way you do not need to query anything, you can just access the resulting data objects by their properties.

Or... why not use the Google client packages via NuGet?

No POCO or client packages in use at this time. Aiming to just use LINQ.

I would recommend to use classes representing the structure of JSON document to parse the data but if you insist on the using LINQ, then first of all do not reuse the lambda parameter name (me) inside the Where for TryGetProperty calls, create separate variables and then use EnumerateArray instead of ToList. Something along these lines (removed usages of GetPropertyNullable since it is not a part of framework AFAIK, also needs checks/validations/safeguards to be added):
string MemberFriendlyName(JsonDocument metadata, string type, string apiName)
{
    string uiName = metadata
        .RootElement
        .GetProperty(type)
        .EnumerateArray()
        .Where(me => 
            (me.TryGetProperty("apiName", out var name)
                && name.GetString() == apiName)
            ||
            (me.TryGetProperty("deprecatedApiNames", out var dep) 
                && dep.EnumerateArray().Any(je => je.GetString() == apiName)))
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .GetProperty("uiName")
        .GetString();
    return uiName;
}


I would propose another approach to use:
    using System;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Linq;      

    public class HelloWorld
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var str = "{\"dimensions\":[{}],\"metrics\":[{\"apiName\":\"keyEvents\",\"uiName\":\"Key events\",\"description\":\"The count of key events. Marking an event as a key event affects reports from time of creation. It doesn\'t change historic data. You can mark any event as key in Google Analytics, and some events (such as `first_open` or `purchase`) are marked as key events by default.\",\"deprecatedApiNames\":[\"conversions\"],\"type\":\"TYPE_FLOAT\",\"category\":\"Event\"},{\"apiName\":\"newUsers\",\"uiName\":\"New users\",\"description\":\"The number of users who interacted with your site or launched your app for the first time (event triggered: first_open or first_visit).\",\"type\":\"TYPE_INTEGER\",\"category\":\"User\"}]}";


            dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
            (stuff as JToken).SelectTokens("metrics[*].apiName").ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Value<string>());
            });
        }
    }

I don't have time now to write all conditions that u need, but u have the starting point and it is easy to take it from here.
